# What is my probability space and measurable space?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I have the following difference equation

$$
\tilde{u}_k = \begin{cases}
u_k & \text{if $\gamma_k = 1$, no signal lost} \\
\tilde{u}_{k-1} & \text{if $\gamma_k = 0$, signal lost}
\end{cases}
$$

which can be rewritten to $\tilde{u}_k = (1 - \gamma_k) \tilde{u}_{k-1} + \gamma_k u_k$. The chance that $\gamma_k = 1$ is $p_\gamma$ and the chance that $\gamma_k = 0$ is $1 - p_\gamma$ for all $k$. As a result we model $\gamma$ using a Markov chain.

Now I am a bit confused on what the random variable/element is in this case, the probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$ and measurable space $(E,\Sigma)$ is?

Clearly $\gamma_k$ is a discrete-time stochastic process which satisfies the Markov property. Further $P$ is clear to me, $P(\gamma = 1) = p_\gamma$ and $P(\gamma = 0) = 1 - p_\gamma$, but $\Omega = F = \{\text{signal lost},\text{no signal lost}\}$? And $\gamma : \Omega \rightarrow E$ with $E = \{0,1\}$? And what would $\Sigma$ be?

Comment: Somebody should probably say it, but to know what the probability space $\Omega$ might be, is not (actually, very rarely) a cogent question  in probability theory. All that counts is that such spaces exist. To see why, imagine that one carefully chooses a space $\Omega$ allowing to build the process $(\tilde u_k)$, then one is said to consider yet another random variable, say Bernoulli and independent of the rest. Should we restart all the construction to get $\Omega'$ "larger" than $\Omega$? This would be wasting some time better spent on actually solving the probability question at hand...

Comment: @Did As my post shows, it quickly does get very tedious...and pointless ;-) That's why I felt compelled to include $C$ as the more relevant sample space, although neither is really needed for probability calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample space for your process $\tilde{u}_k$ relies on three spaces:

1. An abstract sample space $\Omega$, with sample points $\omega_i:=(^i\omega_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}^{i \in R^+}$ Note that $|\Omega|=\aleph^1$.
2. $\gamma(\omega): \Omega \to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which represents all possible infinite sequences of $1$ and $0$.
3. $u(\omega):\Omega \to \times_{k\in \mathbb{N}}E_{u_k}$ - which contains all possible sequences of $u_k$

We can define a sequence of random variables $X(\omega):=\left(x_0,(\gamma_k(\omega)\cdot u_k(\omega))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\right)$, which is just the sequence of element-wise products of $\gamma(\omega)$ and $u(\omega)$,

We can define your process most naturally as another sequence of random variables: $\tilde{u}(\omega)=\left(X_{b_k}(\omega)\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\; \text{ where } b_k=\max\limits_{1\leq j\leq k}\left\{j\cdot\gamma_j(\omega),1\right\}$.

So, the underlying sample space is still abstract, but you could also consider a space $C$ with elements $c=(\gamma(\omega),u(\omega))$ as a the most concrete underlying sample space.

Of course, this is a bit more general than you may like: you did not say that $u(\omega)$ represents a *noiseless* signal. If it is, then your sample space is just No. 2 from above, and you can replace $u(\omega)$ with its deterministic sequence in the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The sample space $\Omega$ is $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, and $\gamma_k(\omega) = \omega_k$ (i.e. an outcome tells you $\gamma_k$ for all natural numbers $k$).  The $\sigma$-field is the Borel $\sigma$-field for the product topology, which is the $\sigma$-field generated
by the $\gamma_k$.

Comment: Sorry can you explain it a bit more in layman terms? Further with $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ you mean the power set right? Meaning $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} = \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \ldots = \{(0),(1),(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,0,0),...\}$?

Comment: $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the space of infinite sequences of zeroes and ones.

Comment: @WG-: What you have attempted to write is the product sigma algebra, not $\Omega=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. The elements you've written are in the product sigma algebra. But, in general, you cannot write a typical element of the sigma algebra. The kind of elements you've written are so-called cylinder events that generate the product sigma algebra.

Comment: This models the sequence $(\gamma_k)$ but one also needs the sequence $(u_k)$ hence this space $\Omega$ does not suffice.